# Why EF creates database file with a different name?

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

I was trying to do the basic database migration according Pluralsight training, however the name of the database file created doesn't match the name specified in the connection string.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0; 
Initial Catalog=eManager.Web; 
Integrated Security=SSPI; 
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\eManager.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Instead of creating **eManager.mdf** it creates **DefaultConnection.mdf**

In the tutorial, it should be **eManager.mdf**.

Any idea why?

My Db Context is defined like this:

```
public class DepartmentDb : DbContext, IDepartmentDataSource
{
    public DepartmentDb() : base("DefaultConnetion")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    IQueryable<Employee> IDepartmentDataSource.Employees
    {
        get { return Employees; }
    }

    IQueryable<Department> IDepartmentDataSource.Departments
    {
        get { return Departments; }
    }
}
```

**Update: Misspelled "DefaultConnetion" in constructor param :))**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
base("DefaultConnetion")
```

with this code, EF will look for a connection string in the app.config with this name, fail (it is called "DefaultConnection", not "DefaultConnetion"), and interpret this string as the database name.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the name into your `DbContext` by doing something like this:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    { }

    //....
}
```